# Using printf with forEach in displayMethod, how to change spacing of individual arrays display

Tags: java, generics, foreach, printf

I am practicing with Generics for a class. I must print to the terminal details about three different arrays and then I run a selection sort and print out the sorted arrays and their max and min values.

My question is, with my main as it is, how can I get the spacing right as shown in the pictures attached?

Here is what my output looks like

[image: My output as is]

And I need spaces inserted and removed to match this output, 
[image: Output I need]

My main question I suppose, is that I need to change the spacing in my string array for example, the spacing I have for my Integer and Char arrays seems to be fine, however, if I change my displayArray method's printf, it affects EVERY one of my array obviously.

How can I change them individually?

Below you will find my Java code for my Main method which runs this all. Thank you.

```java
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Integer[] intArray    = {10, 1, 6, 4, 9, 5, 2, 8, 3, 7};
       Character[] charArray = {'a', 'd', 'g', 'c', 'j', 'f', 'e', 'h', 'i', 'b'};
       String[] stringArray  = {"aa", "dd", "gg", "cc", "jj", "ff", "ee", "hh", "ii", "bb"};

       System.out.printf("%s%n","Original arrays:");
       System.out.printf("%20s","Integer array: " );
       displayArray("Integer", intArray);
       System.out.printf("%20s","Character array:" );
       displayArray("Character", charArray);
       System.out.printf("%20s","String array: " );
       displayArray(String.format("%20s", "String"), stringArray );

       Algorithms algo = new Algorithms();

       System.out.printf("%n%20s","Smallest int: " + algo.getSmallestElement(intArray) );
       System.out.printf("%n%20s","Largest int: " + algo.getLargestElement(intArray) );
       System.out.println();
       System.out.printf("%n%20s","Smallest char: " + algo.getSmallestElement(charArray) );
       System.out.printf("%n%20s","Largest char: " + algo.getLargestElement(charArray) );
       System.out.println();
       System.out.printf("%n%20s","Smallest string: " + algo.getSmallestElement(stringArray) );
       System.out.printf("%n%20s","Largest string: " + algo.getLargestElement(stringArray) );
       System.out.println();
       System.out.printf("%n%s","Sorted Arrays: ");
       algo.sort(intArray);
       System.out.printf("%n%20s","Integer array:"); 
       displayArray("Integer", intArray);
       algo.sort(charArray);
       System.out.printf("%20s","Character array:"); 
       displayArray("Character", charArray);
       algo.sort(stringArray);
       System.out.printf("%20s","String array:"); 
       displayArray("String", stringArray);
       //displayArray(String.format("%20s", "Integer array:"), intArray );
   }// end main mehtod

   public static <E> void displayArray(String label, E[] list) {
       for (E element : list) {
           System.out.printf("%2s", element);
       }// end forEach
       System.out.println();
   }// end display method 

}// end main class
```

Comment: Is the use of the printf method a requirement for this exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the type of e in the displayArray method, and adjust your output accordingly.

```
public static <E> void displayArray(String label, E[] list) {
    for(E element : list) {
        if(element instanceof String)
            System.out.printf("%s", element);
        else
            System.out.printf("%s ", element);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```